# Hibernate 6.4 : org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

Technology stack:
openJdk17
Spring Batch 5
Spring Boot 3
Spring data Jpa 3
Hiberante 6.4

My Entity :
@Entity
@Table(name = "CMN_TXN_DATA")
public class TransactionEntity
{

```
@Column(name = "ID_SGK")
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cmnTxnSeqGenerator", sequenceName = "CMN_TXN_ID_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "cmnTxnSeqGenerator")
private Long cmnTxnSgk;

@Column(name = "WF_EXEC_ID")
private Long executionId;
```

}

This is database seuence  CMN_TXN_ID_SEQ.

Usecase :
While running the job , job will read the data from one table and insert into another table.

****Bulk insert :  transactionRepository.saveAll(chunk.getItems())  **is failing ******

Error:
**org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session**

Try with
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cmnTxnSeqGenerator", sequenceName = "CMN_TXN_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
But with allocationSize , batch insert is not working.
For 1000 records its taking 6 minutes to insert.
And if we remove allocationSize = 1, the below error is coming :

**org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session**

Comment: Issue is with oracle database , on H2 its working.

Comment: This is my database sequence :  Probably i need to increment this according to allocation_size  CREATED 05-MAR-24
LAST_DDL_TIME 05-MAR-24
SEQUENCE_OWNER UST_OWNER
SEQUENCE_NAME CMN_TXN_ID_SEQ
MIN_VALUE 1
MAX_VALUE 999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY 1
CYCLE_FLAG N
ORDER_FLAG N
CACHE_SIZE 0
LAST_NUMBER 436818
PARTITION_COUNT 
SESSION_FLAG N
KEEP_VALUE N

Comment: It got solved by making allocation-size value same as the database sequence in my case its CMN_TXN_ID_SEQ  INCREMENT BY value.  Allocation-size =  Sequence INCREMENT BY